# How to get a notice by Gmail if someone plans a meeting in my Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Had this numerous times: someone planned a meet in my calendar without getting a notice somewhere (preferably by mail) that this happened.

Result: getting of meeting notice 10 min before, without me even knowing it was planned.

Must be some setting to change this?

Comment: I use a Thunderbird client synchronised with my Google calendar. Thunderbird creates pop-up reminders, but only if the event is created with a reminder: it is up to the creator of the event to decide how far in advance is appropriate, although you can specify defaults for new events.

Comment: Have them share the calendar and import their calendar into whatever calendar program your using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done this, you can add/edit notifications in Calendar settings. The default is a popup notification 10 min. before the event so I suspect you haven't edited this.

- Go to Google Calendar.
- Click the Settings gear at top right.
- Choose "Settings" in the dropdown.
- Click the "Calendars" tab (top left).
- Look at your list of Calendars. On the right you can "edit notifications" for each calendar.

In here you can Add/edit a notification, choose to get an email or sms when someone invites you to an event, receive a daily agenda etc.